# The same size force is applied to three balls of different mass. How does the acceleration of the balls depend on their mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Be specific to all the answers, please.

Have a good day.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1):

F = ma.
So acceleration will be F/m1, F/m2, and F/m3.
So the acceleration is inversely proportional to their masses.
(Newtonian Physics!)

Comment: Please read about the [homework-type question policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714).

Answer (score 0):

F = ma, so for example if you have a car that weighs 642kg and is accelerating at 13 meters per second squared, the force is 642 * 13 = 8346N. The measurements I gave are the typical measurements you should use when solving problems like this.